# WPF MVVM: an issue of organising ViewModels

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

what I think I face is a problem of design - one I assume has been solved many times by many people since it seems like it would be very common.

I'm using WPF with XAML and a simple MVVM approach, for the record.

My intention is to create a TreeView, using the MVVM design pattern in WPF.

I have a data model which contains two classes: Scene and Character. Each Scene contains many Characters.

I have created a CharacterViewModel, which is fairly simple (and works fine). Naturally this wraps around the existing Character class.

The Scene class is where I'm getting confused. As I understand it, the SceneViewModel should wrap around the Scene class, just as the CharacterViewModel did for the Character class. But the difference is that Scene contains a list of Characters and thus adds exta complications.

The two options seem to be as follows:

Option 1: Scene contains List of Character and so SceneViewModel also will have that as part of it.

Option 2: Scene contains List of CharacterViewModel and so SceneViewModel will also have that as part of it.

I'm not sure which one to go for to be honest. I suspect it's the second (and      [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial) tutorial seems to agree (example 6 is the heading for the section I'm referring to). The first option seems like it would make things really weird (and also why created the CharacterViewModel at all?) but the second seems strange because it seems to muddy the waters regarding what should be in the model part of the program and what should be in the view model part of the program.

I hope I've explained my problem and I also hope someone can offer some help.

Thanks.

Comment: Your options 1 & 2 are the same (with the exception of will/also being reordered).

Comment: Oh indeed, allow me to edit.

Comment: Your ViewModels don't actually need to resemble your models at all, they should reflect your View. Sometimes they will match and other times they won't, depending on what the View represents. e.g. if your View was just showing counts of actors per scene you might just have a have a SceneListViewModel containing a list of SceneSummaryViewModels with properties Title and ActorCount, and methods to retrieve/save the values. Decide what your View looks like then just create ViewModels with properties/methods to support that, rather than working in the other direction.

Comment: @TheFaithfulLearner: Do any of these answers satisfy your question?

Answer (score 1):

Let me first address this statement:

> ...the SceneViewModel should wrap around the Scene class, just as the CharacterViewModel did for the Character class.

This isn't exactly true. View model should be created for each view. There may be a one-to-one with your model classes, but that isn't a strict part of the MVVM idea. One view may need to present data from multiple "root" model elements (model elements that don't have an explicit relationship like the parent-child relationship in your application), or you may need to have multiple views for a single model element. And to elaborate further, each view model should ideally be isolated from the view technology as much as possible (i.e. a single view model is sufficient to create a WinForms view or a WPF view or an HTML view, etc).

For example, you may have a view that displays data from your `Scene` class. That view may also display some data for each `Character` in your `Scene`. The user may be able to click on a `Character` and open a view just for that `Character` (e.g. a popup). In this case, there may be separate view models to represent the `Character` in the root view and the popup. I tend to name my view model classes according to the root of the view. For an application like yours, I would have something like `SceneViewModel` and `SceneCharacterViewModel` (or `SceneViewModel_Character`, or `CharacterInSceneViewModel` -- any of these names conveys that the class is for representing a `Character` in a view for a `Scene`). This would differentiate that view model from the popup view (which would be `Character`-centric and would be named something like `CharacterViewModel` (or even `CharacterDialogViewModel` or `CharacterPopupViewModel` or `CharacterEditorViewModel`).

Keeping collections in sync between the model and view model is annoying but often necessary. Not *always* necessary, mind you -- there will be cases in which you'll find there are no additional view-model features that you need to add to a model, so it's perfectly acceptable for the view to reference the model directly in this case.

An example of keeping a model collection and view model collection in sync: Suppose your root `SceneView` has a button for each `Character`. That button will display a popup for the `Character`. Suppose further that the `Character` popup doesn't have a similar button because then it would allow the popup to open another popup (etc). You may want to use an `ICommand` implementation so that you can just bind the button to the command. It's definitely not appropriate for the `ICommand` instance to be in the model (even though the command may call a public method on the model). The appropriate place for this would be in the view model for the `Character` in the `Scene` view (not the view model for the `Character` in the popup). For every `Character` in the model, you would need to create a view model that references the `Character` and stores additional view-model stuff (the `ICommand` object).

This means that, as `Character`s are added/removed from the `Scene`, you need to create view models specifically for those `Character`s within the `Scene` view model. I would typically do this:

- At construction time (or whatever time the view model initially receives the model), create a view model for each child object. Put those view models into a public property with a type of something like `ReadOnlyCollection<SceneCharacterViewModel>`. Your view will bind to that collection.
- As child objects are added to the model (either internally or through a public method on the model), the model should notify the view model in an appropriate way. Since the model shouldn't have a direct reference to the view model (not even through an interface -- a model should be completely functional even in a non-UI context, in which there is no view model), the most appropriate way is to use events. You can do this a couple of ways:

  - Expose events from your model like `CharacterAdded`, `CharacterRemoved` or even `CharactersUpdated` (the last of these would be able to communicate either an add or a remove using a single event)
  - `ObservableCollection`s (or `ReadOnlyObservableCollection`s), which are most commonly used in view models, can also be used in models, in which case all the events are already available to you. The downside to this is that processing the events off of these collection types isn't the easiest thing.
  - A third option that is totally different: If your view model or command instance is directly invoking a method like `sceneModel.AddCharacter(newCharacterModel)`, then you can just update your view model immediately after this line without needing any events. I often find myself starting this way because it's simple, but I almost always end up using one of the previous two techniques instead, as those techniques allow the model to notify the view model even in cases where the update is happening internally (e.g., in response to a timed event or asynchronous operation that is controlled by the model).

All of that being said, here's what a "pure" MVVM architecture would look like for your application. Purity can come at the expense of simplicity, so sometimes it's better to take some shortcuts here and there. One common shortcut: In WPF, it's often easier just to put all of your child widget content in the `ItemTemplate` of the `ItemsControl` that is being used to diplay your children, rather than creating a separate `UserControl` for the children.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess from your explanation Scene is the Model and SceneViewModel would wrap additional view related functionality to your model in the view model. Same applies for CharacterViewModel. 
Whatever your view needs to display you would have a SceneViewModel with a list of CharacterViewodel or vice versa. Or like mentioned your could build up a tree structure with your ViewModels.

My personal view of things is, it is important to stay in the ViewModel universe. So when your construct a view model you would inject your model via a service and build up your ViewModel and only have lists with view models. You would need to do some mapping but there are useful frameworks like automapper, etc already available. But remember there are no hard rules with MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your choices, However, I think you just need one View Model and it should contain an `ObservableCollection` of the `Scene`s. I name it `SceneViewModel`:

```
public class SceneViewModel
{
    public SceneViewModel()
    {
        Scene m1 = new Scene() { Name = "Scene1", Characters = new ObservableCollection<Character>() { new Character() { Name="C1" }, new Character() { Name = "C2" } } };
        Scene m2 = new Scene() { Name = "Scene2", Characters = new ObservableCollection<Character>() { new Character() { Name = "D1" }, new Character() { Name = "D2" } } };
        Scene m3 = new Scene() { Name = "Scene3", Characters = new ObservableCollection<Character>() { new Character() { Name = "R1" }, new Character() { Name = "R2" } } };
        _scenes = new ObservableCollection<Scene>() { m1, m2, m3 };
    }

    ObservableCollection<Scene> _scenes;
    public ObservableCollection<Scene> Scenes { get { return _scenes; } set { _scenes = value; } }
}
```

Scene will have an `ObservableCollection` of `Character`s

```
public class Scene : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ObservableCollection<Character> _characters;
    public ObservableCollection<Character> Characters { get { return _characters; } set { _characters = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Characters"); } }

    string _name;
    public string Name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Name"); } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void RaisePropertyChanged(string propname)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propname));
    }
}
```

and at last, `Character`:

```
public class Character : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string _name;
    public string Name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Name"); } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void RaisePropertyChanged(string propname)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propname));
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<TreeView DataContext="{Binding}" ItemsSource="{Binding Scenes}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Characters}"> 
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"></TextBlock> 
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new SceneViewModel(); 
}
```